# Macaw iOS - animate or reverse on tap

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I'm just getting stuck into the Macaw library and trying to do some simple animations on tap events.

I've got a simple animation working whereby if you tap on a node it animates to a new node. Now when you tap again I want to reverse the animation. However the reverse animation doesn't seem to fire.

```
class button: MacawView {
  var animation:Animation?
  var reverse:Bool = false

  required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    let stroke = Stroke(width: 15.0, cap: .round)

    let contents1 = [
        Shape(form: Line(x1: 150.0, y1: 150.0, x2: 175.0, y2: 125.0), stroke: stroke),
        Shape(form: Line(x1: 150.0, y1: 150.0, x2: 225.0, y2: 150.0), stroke: stroke),
        Shape(form: Line( x1: 150.0, y1: 150.0, x2: 175.0, y2: 175.0), stroke: stroke),
        ]

    let contents2 = [
        Shape(form: Line(x1: 130.0, y1: 110.0, x2: 245.0, y2: 110.0), stroke: stroke),
        Shape(form: Line(x1: 130.0, y1: 150.0, x2: 245.0, y2: 150.0), stroke: stroke),
        Shape(form: Line(x1: 130.0, y1: 190.0, x2: 245.0, y2: 190.0), stroke: stroke),
        ]

    let group = contents1.group()

    self.init(node: group, coder: aDecoder)
    animation = group.contentsVar.animation(to: contents2)
    group.onTap { (tapEvent) in
        if(!self.reverse) {
            self.animation?.play()
        } else {
            _ = self.animation?.reverse().play()
        }
        self.reverse = !self.reverse
    }
  }
}
```

I've got a feeling it's because I don't quite understand the lifecylce of Macaw groups and contents. Either that or it's a scope issue in the callback.
The callback is called again when I want it to reverse, and goes into the reverse line, it's just nothing seems to happen.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there was no reverse() method for ShapeAnimation in Macaw.
This pull request fixed the issue
https://github.com/exyte/Macaw/pull/324
You are welcome to check it out